# on new Maven Project: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Spring Tool Suite, with embebbed maven, I get this problem creating a new Maven Project. 
I have tried every answer given in similar posts; cleaning repository and rebuilding, proxies in settings.xml, pointing to the correct xml, using own maven and so on, what am i doing wrong?
Full description of the problem:

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its 
dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

settins.xml

```
<proxies> 
<!-- proxy | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the 
network. | <proxy> <id>optional</id> <active>true</active> 
<protocol>http</protocol> <username>proxyuser</username> 
<password>proxypass</password> <host>proxy.host.net</host> <port>80</port> 
<nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts> </proxy> -->
<proxy>
    <id>proxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>proxy-ccy.houston.hp.com</host>
    <port>8080</port>
</proxy>
<proxy>
    <id>proxy1</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>proxy.austin.hp.com</host>
    <port>8080</port>
</proxy>
</proxies>
```

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.marco.arale</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-arale</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>maven-arale</name>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\Users\lopezbae\Documents\stsworkspace\maven-arale\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\Users\lopezbae\Documents\stsworkspace\maven-arale\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\Users\lopezbae\Documents\stsworkspace\maven-arale\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\lopezbae\Documents\stsworkspace\maven-arale\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\Users\lopezbae\Documents\stsworkspace\maven-arale\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\Users\lopezbae\Documents\stsworkspace\maven-arale\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\Users\lopezbae\Documents\stsworkspace\maven-arale\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\Users\lopezbae\Documents\stsworkspace\maven-    <finalName>maven-arale-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>arale\target</directory>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\lopezbae\Documents\stsworkspace\maven-arale\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\lopezbae\Documents\stsworkspace\maven-arale\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\Users\lopezbae\Documents\stsworkspace\maven-arale\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\lopezbae\Documents\stsworkspace\maven-arale\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: You seemed to be having internet connections problems or are behind a corporate firewall / proxy...which is not correctly configured..Furthermore you pom file looks wrong it contains absolute paths...never use this...

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `maven-resources-plugin` plugin, you can fine code below:

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>           
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>   
    </build>
```

add below code into `settins.xml`:

```
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>optional-proxyUser</username>
      <password>optional-proxyPassword</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>some.demo.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
```

after this add `settings.xml` into project: goto Preferences>Maven>User-Settings>select your settings.xml and click apply and ok.

Comment: sorry, poste the wrong part of the pom.xml. The pom already has that code and the settings is the same as mine, just without the username and password tags, already selected the correct settings, still with problem:(

Comment: then try to  add settings.xml into project: goto Preferences>Maven>User-Settings>select your settings.xml and click apply and ok.

Comment: try to delete `.m2` folder then upgrade your `<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>` version to `<version>2.7</version>`  and update the project and run it.

Comment: same result, i can't see why it fails, it's a simple new Maven Project.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the repository folder [found here ~/.m2/repository] and after that it worked for me.